# Best WiFi channel along with 2.4GHz cordless phone

Tags: wifi

I have a WiFi router and a Panasonic cordless phone, both are running at 2.4 GHz. Both devices are situated nearly 1 meter apart due to physical limitations.

- The router does not support 5 GHz and I have no plan to upgrade it.
- The cordless phone datasheet has no info about the specific frequency in MHz. It just says 2.4 GHz

My questions are:

1. Does this cordless phone transmit ~2.4 GHz signals even when we are not using the phone?
2. If it does interfere, what is the best WiFi channel (2401-2483 MHz) to reduce the possible interference?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this cordless phone transmit ~2.4 GHz signals even when we are not using the phone?

Impossible to know. In Europe, cordless phones are DECT phones, and almost universally use the 1.880–1.900 GHz band reserved for cordless phones. There are DECT bands in the 2.4 GHz band used by wifi, as well, but they're not common – why use a crowded band if you get one to yourself? Anyway, DECT base stations need to periodically transmit their existence in short bursts. These could collide with Wifi in the same band – but they're short enough to not actually matter. That one in tenthousand wifi packets will just be resent (and you lose a lot more wifi packets due to other ISM band devices, far-away wifis, microwave ovens, and receiver temperature).

If your phone actually operates in the 2.4 GHz band, chances are it's already a Wifi device and harmonically co-exists with Wifi devices. No matter whether it is a wifi device, if it was designed to be used in that band, it needs to be able to coexist, otherwise it wouldn't be allowed in that band. So, I doubt your actually solving a real problem here!

> The cordless phone datasheet has no info about the specific frequency in MHz. It just says 2.4 GHz

That's probably the correct amount of information, as it is likely to be some sort of frequency-hopping system, or a system that switches channels very seamlessly when it notices interference.

> If it does interfere, what is the best WiFi channel (2401-2483 MHz) to reduce the possible interference?

All Wifi channels are equally likely or unlikely to be interefered with by your phone. Just pick one in the usual raster (so, channel 1, 5, 9 or 13), or let your router pick one for you.